# What is between { }?

Tags: ruby

There is a piece of code:

```
 def test_sub_is_like_find_and_replace
    assert_equal "one t-three", "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) { $1[0, 1] }
 end
```

I found it really hard to understand what is between `{ }` braces. Could anyone explain it please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{...}` is a block. Ruby will pass the matched value to the block, and substitute the return value of the block back into the string. The [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-sub) documentation explains this more fully:

> In the block form, the current match string is passed in as a parameter, and variables such as $1, $2, $`, $&, and $' will be set appropriately. The value returned by the block will be substituted for the match on each call.

Edit: Per Michael's comment, if you're confused about `$1[0, 1]`, this is just taking the first capture (`$1`) and taking a substring of it (the first character, specifically). $1 is a global variable set to the contents of the first capture after a regex (in true Perl fashion), and since it's a string, the `#[]` operator is used to take a substring of it starting at index 0, with a length of 1.

Comment: I think the OP is confused about the block's cryptic _contents_ here.  `$1[0, 1]`

Comment: `$1`..`$9` are *not* global variables, despite their Dollar sign naming convention. [Docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/re_rdoc.html#label-Special+global+variables) (last paragraph) and [RR Podcast 105](http://rubyrogues.com/105-rr-regular-expressions-with-nell-shamrell/). It's a subtle difference, but nonetheless ;-)

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 2):

The `sub` method either takes two arguments, first being the text to replace replace and the second being the replacement, or one argument being the text to replace and a block defining how to handle the replacement.

The block method is useful if you can't define your replacement as a simple string.

For example:

```
"foo".sub(/(\w)/) { $1.upcase }
# => "Foo"

"foo".sub(/(\w+)/) { $1.upcase }
# => "FOO"
```

The `gsub` method works the same way, but applies more than once:

```
"foo".gsub(/(\w)/) { $1.upcase }
# => "FOO"
```

In all cases, `$1` refers to the contents captured by the brackets `(\w)`.

Your code, illustrated

```
r = "one two-three".sub(/(t\w*)/) do 
  $1 # => "two"
  $1[0, 1] # => "t"
end

r # => "one t-three"
```

Answer (score 0):

`sub` is taking in a regular expression in it. The `$1` is a reserved global variable that contains the match for the regular expression.

The brackets represent a block of code used that will substitute the match with the string returned by the block. In this case

```
puts $1
#=> "two"
puts $1[0, 1]
#=> "t"
```